# Algorithm to get best text color

Tags: algorithm, colors

I'm looking for an algorithm to get the best text color (most pleasing to the eye) from a given background color.

Any idea ?

Comment: Not going to downvote because it's interesting and useful, but you might want to explain "best color" a little more clearly for everyone.

Comment: Widor's got a very good point. Please reword to expand on what you mean by "best color" (most pleasing to the eye, highest contrast, color blindness friendly, whatever).

Comment: Is "pleasingness to the eye" objectively measurable in some way?  If so, how?  If not, do you see why there cannot be any such algorithm?

Answer (score 12):

"The best color" is very subjective and context dependent. It depends on what effect you want: If you want the highest contrast possible, look for complementary colors (that would give you red on green, yellow on blue etc.). If you want colors that are "similar", look for analogous harmonies. If you want to decide between black and white only, measure brightness (hamstergene posted a very good formula for it).

Wherever you go, HSV color model is the key.

Getting complementary or analogous colors is trivial (e.g. `hue_text = (hue_bg + 180) % 360` OR `hue_text = (hue_bg + 30) % 360`).

You can also experiment with value (lightness) and saturation for better contrast. For example, `v_text = 1 - v_bg` could give you dark text on bright background and vice versa (watch out for mid tones!). It doesn't have to be linear - you also could go for a step function like: `if v_bg < 0.5 then v_text = 1 else v_text = 0`, or `if s_bg < 0.5 then s_text = 1 else s_text = 0` (vibrant on pale).

That's just some hints. In a word: **It depends!**

Google for color theory and color harmonies. Some links:

http://www.tigercolor.com/color-lab/color-theory/color-harmonies.htm

http://www.colormatters.com/color-and-design/basic-color-theory

Answer (score 6):

There is no best for everyone.

Say if you need to make sure text will be easily readable, the following simple formula worked well for me:

```
textColor = brightness(backColor) > 0.5 ? black : white;
```

where brightness is defined as

```
brightness(R,G,B) = 0.299*R + 0.587*G + 0.114*B
```

(there are several definitions for “brightness”, I used this one but I think any one would work).

Comment: I came back looking for it and remembering someone gave a better answer, and here you are. :-)